# Getting pylint (or other tool) to catch overlapping exceptions

Tags: python, pylint, flake8, pyflakes

I haven't found any way to get pylint (or other code analysis tools) to catch cases where there are overlapping/redundant exceptions caught like in the following example:

```
"""doc"""
import socket
try:
    pass
except (ConnectionError, IOError, OSError, socket.error):
    # ConnectionError inherits from OSError
    # socket.error and IOError are aliases for OSError
    pass
```

Here I would like to get a complaint about ConnectionError, IOError and socket.error already being covered by OSError in the except-clause.

```
In [1]: import socket

In [2]: OSError
Out[2]: builtins.OSError

In [3]: socket.error
Out[3]: builtins.OSError

In [4]: IOError
Out[4]: builtins.OSError

In [5]: ConnectionError, ConnectionError.__bases__
Out[5]: (builtins.ConnectionError, (builtins.OSError,))
```

Does this exists?
If not, would this be a good/bad idea?

Comment: Feel free to submit an proposal to [pylint's GitHub](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint). For what I know, writing this check is possible with pylint machinery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now implemented here:
[Overlap-except-checker](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical_reference/extensions.html#overlap-except-checker)